# How to split a string with whitespace and underscore in Python

Tags: python, split

I hope this will find you guys well, can you please show me how to split text with whitespace and underscore?
For Example,

```
txt= "Im Alex_from_canada"
```

Output should be

```
['Im','Alex','frpm','canada']
```

Looking Forward, Stay blessed

Comment: Use `re.split()` with a regular expression that matches whitespace and underscore.

Comment: Your question needs more details, do you need to split a string that contains whitespace and underscore (`split()` and `split('_')`) or do you need to insert those characters into a string to split it ?

Comment: Please *research* a question using online resources.  SO is used for *specific* programming questions, not “how to I do this …”.

Comment: @TitouanL, I just want to split a string that contains both whitespace and underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like :

```
import re

r = re.compile("\s+|_")
s = "bal1      bla2_bla3"

print(r.split(s)) --->['bal1', 'bla2', 'bla3']
```